# categoryBitMask Returning UInt32.max

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

I am working on a game with a variety of collisions. I have created an Enumeration as follows:

```
enum CollisionCategories: UInt32 {
    case localPlayer = 1
    case ball = 2
    case remotePlayer = 4
    case scene = 8
    case goal = 16
}
```

I then created some category variables:

```
let localPlayerCategory: UInt32 = CollisionCategories.localPlayer.rawValue
let ballCategory: UInt32 =  CollisionCategories.ball.rawValue
let remotePlayerCategory: UInt32 =  CollisionCategories.remotePlayer.rawValue
let sceneCategory: UInt32 = CollisionCategories.scene.rawValue
let goalCategory: UInt32 =  CollisionCategories.goal.rawValue
```

Here is where I print the info

```
func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    print("Body A: " + String(contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask))
    print("Body B: " + String (contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask) + "\n")

}
```

However, when the goal and ball collide it returns the following:

```
Body A: 4294967295
Body B: 2
```

Body B is correctly the ball category; however, Body A is clearly off. Here is how I create the goal node:

```
let goal2 = self.newGoal()
goal2.zRotation = CGFloat(M_PI)
goal2.position = CGPoint(x: (gameFrame!.frame.width / 2), y: 0)
let bottom2 = SKPhysicsBody(edgeFromPoint: CGPoint(x: -(goal2.frame.width), y:-(goal2.frame.height / 2)), toPoint: CGPoint(x: 0, y:-(goal2.frame.height / 2)))
bottom2.categoryBitMask = sceneCategory
let top2 = SKPhysicsBody(edgeFromPoint: CGPoint(x: -(goal2.frame.width), y:(goal2.frame.height / 2)), toPoint: CGPoint(x: 0, y:(goal2.frame.height / 2)))
top2.categoryBitMask = sceneCategory
let back2 = SKPhysicsBody(edgeFromPoint: CGPoint(x: -(goal2.frame.width), y:(goal2.frame.height / 2)), toPoint: CGPoint(x: -(goal2.frame.width), y:-(goal2.frame.height / 2)))
back2.categoryBitMask = goalCategory
goal2.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(bodies: [bottom2,top2,back2])
//goal2.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = goalCategory
goal2.physicsBody!.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true
goal2.physicsBody!.affectedByGravity = false
goal2.physicsBody!.dynamic = false
```

As you can see in the line I commented out above, I have also tried setting the entire physics body to be the goal, rather than just the section to see if that was causing the issue. It was not.

Here is how I create the ball's physics properties:

```
ball.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = localPlayerCategory | sceneCategory | goalCategory
ball.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = ballCategory
ball.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = goalCategory
```

So, can anyone can explain why they think bodyA's categoryBitMask is returning the max UInt32? Please note that EVERY collision except for the ball hitting the goal works just fine.

Also, quick side question: Does anyone know how bodyA and bodyB are selected? Why which is which? Thanks!

Comment: Why are you get the raw value instead the value? Your ball is correct because CollisionCategories.ball.rawValue == CollisionCategories.ball .

Comment: @SimonePistecchia I am not sure what you mean... In order to get the UInt32 value you have to run rawValue. You can't set the categoryBitMask otherwise.

Comment: Goal 2 has no categoryBitMask,  so the default is UInt32.max

Comment: Body A and B are not determined, nor can it be.  The system does a lot of optimizations to ensure the fastest results possible,  so depending on how A and B come on the stack, will be the order they come in via the method

Comment: Thanks @Knight0fDragon Also, Goal 2's physics body does not, but the part of the physics body the ball hits does have a categoryBitMask. I also tried witth setting the entire goal's physics body categoryBitMask to get the same result.

Comment: What? Then whatever ball is hitting does not have category bit mask set.  Nodes have a name property, assign names and print the name, you will see what is going on

Comment: @Knight0fDragon It is, in fact, hitting goal2; however, it seems the issue is with `SKPhysicsBody(bodies: [SKPhysicsBody])`. It looks like you can't use a `categoryBitMask` with that initialization. According to the documentation only the shapes of those bodies are used, not the properties.

Comment: Oh, yes, I see what you are trying to do.  It merges the physics body shapes together,  you still only have 1 body,  it is not children bodies

Comment: if you want to have 2 bodies with 2 different categories, then use 2  children nodes, and assign each node a separate body

Answer (score 0):

According to https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsBody_Ref/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SKPhysicsBody/bodyWithBodies: The properties of the bodies used are ignored. Only their shapes are used to construct the new physics body. This means that individual sections cannot have their own `categoryBitMask`. I will have to use a separate node to get the result I want.

Comment: I suggest you declare your UInt32 variables in binary. So 2 would be 0b10 and 4 would be 0b100; this prevents you from using rawValue.

Comment: @JozemiteAppsI am actually doing that now. I was just testing anything I could find on why it might not be working. Works fine now, I just had to add an extra node. Thanks!